# winform dynamically resizing controls

Tags: winforms

Good Day,

I have a Windows Form with two group boxes.  One contains a report and the other will contain some text boxes to critique the Report.  At the bottom of the form, I have three buttons.  The first button will display the group box with the multiple text boxes.  The second button will submit the data.  The third one to clear the text boxes.

```
--------------------------------     --------------------------------
|------------------------------|     |------------------------------|
||                            ||     ||                            ||
||                            ||     ||                            ||
||         Report Viewer      ||     ||       Report Viewer        ||
||                            ||     ||                            ||
||                            ||     ||                            ||
||                            ||     ||----------------------------||
||                            ||     ||----------------------------||
||                            ||     ||                            ||
||                            ||     ||                            ||
||                            ||     ||       Multiple Text Boxes  ||
||                            ||     ||                            ||
|------------------------------|     ||----------------------------||
||       Buttons              ||     ||          Buttons           ||
--------------------------------     --------------------------------
    Form Initially Launches             Button to critique Report 
                                        has been clicked and now 
                                        shows multiple Text Boxes
```

When my form launches, the group box with the multiple text boxes do not display, when I click on one of the buttons, then the group box appears.

Here's my problem.  I want the height of the first group box to take up the height of the both group boxes until I click on the button on the bottom.  Now if the form height was a fixed value, then this isn't a problem.  But if the user is allowed to resize the form, I always want to make sure the the first group box height is always the same.  But when I click on the button to show the mutiple text boxes, I want it that group box to be positioned at the bottom.

I've set the anchor properties appropriately for both views, but I'm not 100% sure how to make my report viewer group box occupy the entire space (except the button area) without having to set the form height programmatically.

Any suggestions?

coson

Comment: Hello, your use of "left and right" and "first and and second" one interchangably make it difficult to always tell which boxes you are referring to in your illustration.  Also regarding your question have you tried playing with the "Dock" property of the controls? Setting that to "Fill" will make a child take up the entire available space of the parent.

Comment: my apologies on the confusion.  I'll edit.

Comment: Use a TableLayoutPanel() and then you can dynamically change the "span" of each control when add/remove them.

Comment: Interesting approach, I'll give it a whirl.